# Как сделать кнопку в Android studio

Tags: android, button

Я хочу сделать кнопку с фоновой картинкой, закруглениями по углам, текстом и рамкой чёрного цвета. Для того чтобы сделать закругление и рамку используется команда background и чтобы сделать задний фон кнопки используется та же самая команда. Пробовал через FrameLayout но мне нужно 5 таких кнопок и чтобы они находились друг пот другом. А при использовании команды FrameLayout они наезжают друг на друга. Как мне быть ?

Comment: Используйте LinearLayout и свойство android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 1):

По правилам SO один вопрос - один вопрос, как бы странно это не звучало. А у вас два, про оформление кнопки и про их расположение. На будущее учтите это и задавайте вопросы отдельно друг от друга.

Оформление. Не уверен как вы закругляете углы атрибутом background, то но, что вам нужно - это drawable, описанный xml. В ресурсах, в папке drawable создайте новый файл my_bg.xml и положите в него следующее:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >//тут говориться, что рисовать в backgounde надо прямоугольник. Еще есть oval, line и ring. Почитайте отдельно про них
    <solid
        android:color="@color/myBackground"> //solid - сплошная заливка. Цвет указываем из ресурсов, либо указываем прям тут color="#FF0000FF"
    </solid>
    <corners
        //указываем радиус закругления углов. Можно указать каждому углу свой. Ссылаемся на ресурсы или сразу числом radius="5dp"
        android:radius="@dimen/search_corner_radius">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

У вашей кнопки пишем атрибут android:backgroud="@drawable/my_bg", теперь у нее будут углы скруглены и залит цвет согласно xml из drawable

Расположение. Во FrameLayout можно прижимать объекты к краям/центрам лайаута с различными отступами, но пересечения объектов он не отлавливает. Используйте ConstraintLayout, если расположение довольно мудреное, или LinearLayout, если кнопки идут просто в ряд вертикально или горизонтально

Comment: но мне нужна кнопка c фоновой картинкой формата png или jpg. Задний фон в виде картинки а не заливки цвета